# Postgres 9.3 pg_stat_activity.query length won't change

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, configuration, truncate

There are a few large SQLs tying up connections to the database over time and I'd like to be able to see the queries but pg_stat_activity.query truncates anything over 256 chars by default so I edited my postgresql.conf to contain

```
track_activities = on
track_activity_query_size = 2048
```

However even after changing this and restarting postgres

```
select query from pg_stat_activity;
select pg_stat_get_backend_activity(id);
```

Still returned only the first 256 characters of an SQL.

I know I am editing the right config file as its the one returned by

```
show conf_file;
```

But I'm not sure why it isn't showing any more than 256 characters.

Comment: What are you using to run the query? pgAdmin truncates output columns, and I think 256 characters might be the default.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query length did change, I just couldn't see it as pgAdmin was truncating the output too.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old but I needed the same function recently.  You have a couple of choices if you want to run your query from PgAdmin (rather than resort to the command line).

1. Firstly, you can change the length of the output.  In the main PgAdmin window go to `File > Options > Query Tool > Query Editor > Max. characters per column` (where you'll see the default value of 256).
2. Alternatively you can send the output to a file.  Instead of clicking the usual little green 'go' arrow to execute the command, look two buttons to the right.  There is an icon composed of little green arrow and a blue floppy-disk.  This is 'Execute query, write results to file'.  This will give you everything in a handy csv file that you could open in a text editor to see everything.